# Why Can I Access Private Variable From Outside Class?

Tags: java, private

I was given the task to find out how to view but not edit a private int from another class. I tried some overly complicated things, but what worked is this:

```
public int getC() { 
return myC; 
 }
```

myC is a private int. Is it really this easy to give another class access to a private var? I thought they couldn't be shared. Could someone explain why this is allowed? Thanks.

Comment: no you can't , you are giving access via a getter, it is a good practice, because if that  outer class can access myC directly you are stuck with it your class have to have if for life time otherwise you will be breaking others code, also you can put any validation on what to be assigned to that variable, but if you use getter() tomorrow you can make it return something else and also can put validation code

Comment: To be clear, it **is** really easy to bypass `private` through *reflection*. This is simple encapsulation, you return `myC` but could (if the requirements changed) `return d` where `d` is some other `int`. But even still, with reflection, someone can access your `private` fields. So there is no **strong** guarantee that someone can't access `private` fields.

Answer (score 0):

You created a **public** getter function to access the private variable. So if another class has an instance of your class  as its local variable, it can use the **public** function(getter) to access the **private** variable of your original class.

Comment: so using a public method to share a private variable is pretty much the same as just making a public variable? thats great

Answer (score 0):

The only way to expose private fields is through `accessors` aka `getters`.

But you should follow 2 rules:

- Avoid the temptation to expose directly all your private fields via getters(ide shortcuts). Only add them if really needed.
- If the type you expose is not immutable take care of not `escape references` by return defensive copies

Exemple:

```java
private Date date;
public Date date() {
   return date;
}
```

This code breaks encapsulation and it is the same as doing this.

`public Date date;`

To solve this you have 2 solutions

- Return a defensive copy of your date

```java
public Date date() {
   return new Date(date.getTime());
}
```

- Use immutable version of Date -> `LocalDate`

Same logic applies for collection types.